# No output when testing the AD620 amplifier with a function generator

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I have a problem testing the AD620 amplifier using a function generator.
I'm injecting a 100 mV sinusoid, and with the gain of a 1k resistor. In this configuration I would have a 5 V signal at the output, but I don't observe anything. What am I doing wrong? GND is common for the battery, function generator and oscilloscope. I'm using two 9 V batteries to power the circuit:

[image]

Comment: I can't see any obvious gotchas there. Post a photograph of how it's built. Post your measurement of the DC voltage on EVERY pin. What's the frequency of your sinuosoid? What instrument are you using to measure your AC out? What AC voltage does it measure on pin 3?

Comment: With a resistor of 1 k, you should get a gain of 50 ...

Answer (score -1):

Here is my circuit ... It works well.

[image]

Comment: OP is asking what they did wrong. Though this may work, I don't think it really answers the question very well.

Comment: OP does not say what was done completely, working frequency ... Injecting 1 mHz at 100 mV does nothing through 0.47 uF ... Not complete description.

Comment: Thank you very much Antonio 51, reproduce the test circuit you gave me here, but I still have a few millivolts at the output. I still didn't get what I expected.

Comment: What did you do ? Could you check the power supplies?

Comment: I wired it exactly like your circuit. I have a function generator with alligator type test leads, where the red one I connected to pin 3, and the black one to pin 2. The black one I also connected to 0V.
I have two 9V batteries connected in series to provide positive and negative voltage, the center of this connection is 0V.
I'm thinking the chip may have been damaged, as I've made several attempts.
For an instrumentation amplifier, what would be a good replacement for the AD620?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I think AD620 damaged. See INA818, but don't know the price and availability.